# Filter algorithm for mutual exclusion: Weak fairness

Tags: concurrency, mutual-exclusion

I was referring to this filter algorithm notes:
http://cs.nyu.edu/wies/teaching/ppc-14/material/lecture02.pdf

It says, It provides weak fairness and some thread can be taken overtaken arbitary number of times. (slide 98)

I am not able to understand this part, as last one to write the victim value has to wait and already waiting thread moves to next level, so how can one thread be overtaken here?.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider 4 threads (t0, t1, t2 and t3) using the filter lock to get a mutual exclusion.

We assume that t0 gets stuck in level 0, t1 in level 1 and so on. Consequently t3 enters its critical section and unlocks the lock afterwards. Note: t0 to t2 are stuck in `while((∃k != i) level[k] >= L) && victim[L] == i) {};` which is actually several lines of code (see [Filter Lock Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19909764/4576488)). From now on I will refer to this piece of code as (C1). Now t2 goes on with entering the critical section and unlocking and then t1. This means t0 could leave level 0's (C1)... However this doesn't mean it can not be overtaken! It is likely that by now t3, t2 and t1 want to acquire the lock again. Consequently one of the three threads is filtered out and stuck in level 0s (C1), because one thread is the "victim", lets say t1. While t0 fulfills all requirements to leave (C1) it could still be in the for-loop of (C1) as it might "run slower" due to various architectural reasons. This allows t2 and t3 to overtake t0.