# Independent Thread Scheduling since Volta

Tags: multithreading, cuda, nvidia, scheduling, gpgpu

Nvidia introduced a new Independent Thread Scheduling for their GPGPUs since Volta. In case CUDA threads diverge, alternative code paths are not executed in blocks but instruction-wise. Still, divergent paths can not be executed at the same time since the GPUs are SIMT as well. This is the original article:

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/inside-volta/ (scroll down to "Independent Thread Scheduling").

I understood what this means. What I don't understand is, in which way this new behavoir accelerates code. Even the before/after diagrams in the above article do not reflect an overall speed-up.

My question: Which kinds of divergent algorithms will run faster on Volta (and newer) due to the described new scheduling?

Comment: Have you read the part about "Starvation-Free Algorithms"?

Comment: One small speedup advantage is that the scheduler can choose the divergent branch for which resources are free at that time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of the feature is not necessarily to accelerate code.

An important purpose of the feature is to enable reliable use of programming models such as producer-consumer within a warp (amongst threads in the same warp) that would have been either brittle or prone to hang using the previous thread schedulers pre-volta.

The typical example IMO of which you can find various examples here on the `cuda` tag, is people trying to negotiate for atomic locks among threads in the same warp. This would have been ["brittle"](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-lock-using-atomiccas/34099) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45718781/thread-warp-local-lock-in-cuda/45723726#45723726)) or [not workable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31194291/cuda-mutex-why-deadlock/31195230#31195230) (hangs) on previous architectures. It works well, on volta, in my experience.

[Here is another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70570671/cuda-program-hangs-filter-lock/70586153#70586153) of an algorithm that just hangs on pre-volta, but "works" (does not hang) on volta+.